# Design Patterns - What pattern is this?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets say I have the following structure in java:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class User extends AbstractEntity { ... }

@Entity
public class SuperUser extends User { ... }

@Entity
public class RegularUser extends User { ... }
```

This project is structured in RESTful endpoints with 3 layers (Resources, Services and Repositories) with generic abstractions:

```
public class AbstractRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> { ... }
```

now I want to have some DB methods executed over all types of `User`, so I created this Repository layer:

```
public class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> { ... }
```

Can it be called an Adapter or maybe Bridge, since its executing logic that kinda encapsulate the funcionality of two other classes (`RegularUserRepository` and `SuperUserRepository`)?

Comment: I think you mean `AbstractRepository<T extends AbstractEntity>`?

Comment: So every superclass is now a design pattern?

Comment: There is a delegate pattern In case `UserRepository` uses `RegularUserRepository` & `SuperUserRepository`  to delegate it's work. I wouldn't call that Adapter since you don't adapt from a to b, and I wouldn't call it bridge because there is nothing intended to decouple implementation from abstraction.

Comment: @zapl Lets say it delegate to `RegularUserRepository` and `SuperUserRepository`, then it is called what? Facade? Delegate?

Comment: Delegate would be the name of regular & super repositories. I don't know how to call the "delegator". Facade has a specific meaning ("Provides a simplified interface") that I don't see here either. What you could consider: access to multiple repositories is often bundled in the service layer, especially when there is actual "logic" involved.

Comment: @zapl That's exact the point, there is no logic.. Seems wrong to me to build a service layer around it

Comment: Not much of a pattern but since you are using composition to build the UserRepository, maybe call it "composite"?

Comment: @zapl, this is most definitely not a [Composite](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Gang-of-Four Design Pattern here. There are two kinds of polymorphism.

1. [Subtype Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) - due to the inheritance relationship between `User` and  its child classes.
2. [Parametric Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) - due to the generic relationship between `AbstractRepository` and `AbstractEntity`.